# when to use Unpooled in netty

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to figure out when to use [Unpooled](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html) in Netty.  Some examples show wrapped the byte[] in `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer`, and some examples show just

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(bytes); // where bytes is just byte[]
```

Is there a guideline on when to use Unpooled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a `byte[]` to a Netty `write` method is equivalent to passing an unpooled `ByteBuf`.  We can see this in the source code for [`ByteArrayEncoder`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.1.13.Final/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/bytes/ByteArrayEncoder.java), which internally calls `Unpooled#wrappedBuffer(byte[])`:

```
@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    out.add(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(msg));
}
```

Therefore, there is no underlying difference between passing `byte[]` and passing a `ByteBuf` created yourself by calling `Unpooled#wrappedBuffer(byte[])`.  The latter is perhaps more explicit about calling out the use of an unpooled buffer, in case the use of pooled vs. unpooled is significant in the context of a particular application.

In case you need more details on pooled buffers, the Netty "New and noteworthy in 4.0" wiki page has a good introduction in the [Pooled buffers](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html#wiki-h3-10) section.